# Iterate through a log file and use a regular expression to extract a time value from line

Tags: regex, perl

I have a perl script creates a text file, writes captured lines from a garbage collection log to it and saves the file in an archived/timestamped folder. The file will have lines that look like this:

> 413489.272: [GC [PSYoungGen: 323892K->3126K(332352K)] 623290K->303976K(1031424K), 0.0253970 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
>
> 413503.531: [GC [PSYoungGen: 319094K->7280K(333760K)] 619944K->310249K(1032832K), 0.0614640 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs]
>
> 413521.441: [GC [PSYoungGen: 324592K->6867K(333056K)] 627561K->310363K(1032128K), 0.0574120 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs]
>
> ```
>                                        ...
> ```

What I'd like to do is iterate through these lines in the file, and use a regular expression to get the value of the "real" time (e.g. `real=0.06 secs`, but just the 0.06), and store it in a `$time` variable. I figure a positive lookbehind would work for this, something like `/(?<=real=)\d\.\d\d/`, but that is not working.

In the end my script would look along the lines of:

```
open LOG,"<","./report/archive/reports-$now/gclog.txt" or die "Unable to read file: $!";
    #while there is lines in the file
        #regex to match time value -> store in variable
        #print variable (just as a check for now)
        #some other stuff not really relevant to this question
close LOG;
```

I am fairly new to perl, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the negative look behind, just a capture.

Use:

```
my ($time) = /\breal=([0-9.]+)/;
```

The `\b` is probably not necessary, but I always prefer to match my word boundaries just in case.

The `()` cause it to capture the output, which is returned as an array. I, then, put the returned value in the variable named `$time`. The capture value is also available in `$1`, but I prefer to return it this way.

Comment: It must be `[0-9.]+` or you only match one digit or dot.

Comment: @zostay

I've tried your regex in my script and I've been getting a weird error in return. `Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at reportloop.pl line 149, <LOG> line 1.` Any ideas why? I can provide the rest of my script if it helps.

Comment: That means you tried to match against an undefined string. Without seeing how your loop is constructed, I can't really tell you why. Probably you are performing some other operation in your loop that is setting `$_` to `undef`. If you copy the line read from `<LOG>` into a variable like `my $foo = $_`, you can apply the regex like this `my ($time) = $foo =~ /.../` to try and fix the problem.